# Inconsistant number of rows pulled

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to really stroke some data.  With the following query, I sometimes get an extra row that has all NULLS.  If I comment out the "isnumeric" in the where statement, and use the one below it that is currently commented out, I get a consistant number, but when I switch back to "isnumeric", I sometimes get that NULL row.

I assume this something faulty in my syntax.  Anyone have any idea ideas?

Thanks!

Matt

```
select distinct 
   AROBP_A.IDINVC     as TAP_AROBP_A_IDINVC,
   AROBP_A.IDCUST     as TAP_AROBP_A_IDCUST,
   ARCUS.NAMECUST     as TAP_ARCUS_NAMECUST,
   ARIBH.DATEINVC     as TAP_ARIBH_DATEINVC,
   ARIBH.TEXTTRX      as TAP_ARIBH_TEXTTRX,
   ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT   as TAP_ARIBH_AMTINVCTOT_ABS,
   TAP_ARIBH_AMTINVCTOT =
                      case ARIBH.TEXTTRX
                      when 3
                      then - ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT
                      else ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT
                      end,
   AROBP_A.AMTPAYMTC  as TAP_AROBP_A_AMTPAYMTC,
   TAP_INV_DIFF =     case ARIBH.TEXTTRX
                      when 3
                      then AROBP_A.AMTPAYMTC - ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT
                      else AROBP_A.AMTPAYMTC + ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT
                      end,
   AROBP_A.DATEBTCH   as TAP_AROBP_A_DATEBTCH,
   AROBP_A.TRXTYPE    as TAP_AROBP_A_TRXTYPE,
   AROBP_A.TRANSTYPE  as TAP_AROBP_A_TRANSTYPE,
   AROBP_A.FISCPER    as TAP_AROBP_A_FISCPER,
   AROBP_A.FISCYR     as TAP_AROBP_A_FISCYR,
   ARSAP.NAMEEMPL     as TAP_ARSAP_NAMEEMPL,
   ARSAP2.NAMEEMPL    as TAP_ARSAP2_NAMEEMPL
into #TMPACCPAC
from GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARIBH ARIBH
right join GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.AROBP AROBP_N on ARIBH.IDINVC = AROBP_N.IDINVC
left  join GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.AROBP AROBP_A on ARIBH.IDINVC = AROBP_A.IDINVC
left  join GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARCUS ARCUS   on ARIBH.IDCUST = ARCUS.IDCUST
left  join GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARSAP ARSAP   on ARCUS.CODESLSP1 = ARSAP.CODESLSP
left  join GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARSAP ARSAP2  on ARIBH.CODESLSP1 = ARSAP2.CODESLSP
where AROBP_N.FISCYR = '2014' and AROBP_N.FISCPER = '03'
  and
  isnumeric(AROBP_N.IDINVC) = 1
  --AROBP_N.IDINVC not like '[A-Z]%' and AROBP_N.IDINVC not like '%[A-Z]'
order by TAP_ARSAP_NAMEEMPL, TAP_AROBP_A_IDCUST, TAP_AROBP_A_IDINVC;

select * from #TMPACCPAC
order by TAP_ARSAP_NAMEEMPL, TAP_AROBP_A_IDCUST, TAP_AROBP_A_IDINVC;

drop table #TMPACCPAC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as follows and test again, your `NULL` rows should not come back. I think your problem is coming from both `RIGHT` and `LEFT` `OUTER JOIN` to the same table `GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.AROBP`. if you don't need to return results from that table if not match is `GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARIBH` than I would just change to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and just remove `RIGHT` join completely other wise use `FULL OUTER JOIN` as it is below in query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AROBP_A.IDINVC AS TAP_AROBP_A_IDINVC
       ,AROBP_A.IDCUST AS TAP_AROBP_A_IDCUST
       ,ARCUS.NAMECUST AS TAP_ARCUS_NAMECUST
       ,ARIBH.DATEINVC AS TAP_ARIBH_DATEINVC
       ,ARIBH.TEXTTRX AS TAP_ARIBH_TEXTTRX
       ,ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT AS TAP_ARIBH_AMTINVCTOT_ABS
       ,TAP_ARIBH_AMTINVCTOT = CASE ARIBH.TEXTTRX
                                 WHEN 3 THEN -ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT
                                 ELSE ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT
                               END
       ,AROBP_A.AMTPAYMTC AS TAP_AROBP_A_AMTPAYMTC
       ,TAP_INV_DIFF = CASE ARIBH.TEXTTRX
                         WHEN 3 THEN AROBP_A.AMTPAYMTC - ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT
                         ELSE AROBP_A.AMTPAYMTC + ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT
                       END
       ,AROBP_A.DATEBTCH AS TAP_AROBP_A_DATEBTCH
       ,AROBP_A.TRXTYPE AS TAP_AROBP_A_TRXTYPE
       ,AROBP_A.TRANSTYPE AS TAP_AROBP_A_TRANSTYPE
       ,AROBP_A.FISCPER AS TAP_AROBP_A_FISCPER
       ,AROBP_A.FISCYR AS TAP_AROBP_A_FISCYR
       ,ARSAP.NAMEEMPL AS TAP_ARSAP_NAMEEMPL
       ,ARSAP2.NAMEEMPL AS TAP_ARSAP2_NAMEEMPL
    INTO #TMPACCPAC
    FROM GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARIBH ARIBH
    FULL OUTER JOIN GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.AROBP AROBP_A
        ON ARIBH.IDINVC = AROBP_A.IDINVC
    LEFT  JOIN GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARCUS ARCUS
        ON ARIBH.IDCUST = ARCUS.IDCUST
    LEFT  JOIN GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARSAP ARSAP
        ON ARCUS.CODESLSP1 = ARSAP.CODESLSP
    LEFT  JOIN GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARSAP ARSAP2
        ON ARIBH.CODESLSP1 = ARSAP2.CODESLSP
    WHERE AROBP_A.FISCYR = '2014'
        AND AROBP_A.FISCPER = '03'
        AND ISNUMERIC(AROBP_A.IDINVC) = 1
  --AROBP_A.IDINVC not like '[A-Z]%' and AROBP_A.IDINVC not like '%[A-Z]'
ORDER BY TAP_ARSAP_NAMEEMPL
       ,TAP_AROBP_A_IDCUST
       ,TAP_AROBP_A_IDINVC;

SELECT *
    FROM #TMPACCPAC
    ORDER BY TAP_ARSAP_NAMEEMPL
       ,TAP_AROBP_A_IDCUST
       ,TAP_AROBP_A_IDINVC;

DROP TABLE #TMPACCPAC;
```

than as a test replace `AND ISNUMERIC(AROBP_A.IDINVC) = 1` with  `AND ISNUMERIC(ARIBH.IDINVC) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer to your problem but certainly worth looking at , The problem with `ISNUMERIC()` function is sometimes it parses a character value as Numeric value. for example see below ....

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Value NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('0123'),('123456'),('12345e2'),('1232e5'),
('aaa55'),('5655e512'),('asas5'),('aabbcc')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT Value
      ,ISNUMERIC(Value) AS Is_Numeric
      ,CASE WHEN Value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                        AS Is_Like_Number
FROM @Table
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════════╗
║  Value   ║ Is_Numeric ║ Is_Like_Number ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 0123     ║          1 ║              1 ║ 
║ 123456   ║          1 ║              1 ║
║ 12345e2  ║          1 ║              0 ║
║ 1232e5   ║          1 ║              0 ║
║ aaa55    ║          0 ║              0 ║
║ 5655e512 ║          0 ║              0 ║
║ asas5    ║          0 ║              0 ║
║ aabbcc   ║          0 ║              0 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Now if you look at the results returned by the `ISNUMERIC()` Function and `Like Operator`, is numeric parses values `12345e2` and `1232e5` as numeric values. the reason is ISNUMERIC function sees these values as `12345x10^2` and `1232x10^5`.

Therefore when you use ISNUMERIC function instead of LIKE operator you get unexpected reuslts. I would suggest sticking to LIKE operator it is more reliable and less error prone.